# Как проверить string на ненужные символы в с#

Tags: c#, строки

Условия задачи: *Дано расстояние в сантиметрах. Найти число полных метров в нем.*

Хочу запретить пользователю вводить что-то кроме цифр с помощью еще одного if; я так понимаю нужно использовать Char.IsLetter для этого, но синтаксис у меня никак не выходит, что бы я не пробовал :(

```
Console.Write("Enter amount of cm: ");
int cm = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (cm < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input must be positive value");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Amount of meters " + CompleteMeters(cm));
}

static int CompleteMeters(int cm)
{
    return cm / 100;
}
```

Comment: лично я не вижу никакого `if`'а с `char.IsLetter`. дополните код, пожалуйста

Comment: используйте Regex

Comment: @MikeWaters `int.TryParse`?

Answer (score 4):

Простой метод: используйте `int.TryParse`.

```cs
Console.Write("Enter amount of cm: ");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
if (s == null) // такое может быть, если входной поток закончился
{              // например, юзер ввёл в стандартной консоли Windows Ctrl-Z или
               // поток ввода был перенаправлен и завершился
    Console.WriteLine("Stream ended");
    return;
}
if (int.TryParse(s, out int cm))
{
    if (cm < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input must be positive value");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Amount of meters " + CompleteMeters(cm));
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input must be a number");
}
```

Более интересный вариант, при котором мы не даём юзеру ввести ничего, кроме числа:

```cs
Console.Write("Enter amount of cm: ");
int cm;
StringBuilder inputSoFar = new StringBuilder();
while (true)
{
    char c = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar;
    if (c == '\x08') // backspace
    {
        if (inputSoFar.Length > 0)
        {
            inputSoFar.Length--;
            Console.Write("\x08 \x08");
        }
    }
    else if (char.IsDigit(c)) // digit
    {
        inputSoFar.Append(c);
        if (int.TryParse(inputSoFar.ToString(), out cm))
            Console.Write(c);
        else
            inputSoFar.Length--;
    }
    else if (c == '\x0d') // enter
    {
        if (int.TryParse(inputSoFar.ToString(), out cm))
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Amount of meters " + CompleteMeters(cm));
```

Поскольку трюки наподобие `Console.ReadKey` работают лишь если у нас интерактивная сессия, и ввод-вывод не перенаправлен, возможно, вы захотите добавить в начале проверку:

```cs
// (кажется, такая проверка правильная)
if (!Environment.UserInteractive || Console.IsInputRedirected ||
        Console.IsOutputRedirected)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Direct work with console not available");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю не ломать голову ненужными проверками, достаточно добавить структуру [try-catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch):

```
Console.Write("Enter amount of cm: ");
try
{
    int cm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите число!");
}
```